# Cannot make minecraft.jar executable

Tags: minecraft

Im trying to excute the minecraft.jar. Ive tried to run several commands but always coming back with "unable to access jarfile"

My file is stored on my downloads and I am the owner it says on file properties. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to run this command?

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
```

othwise make it executable like this :

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/minecraft.jar
```

and than run it `./minecraft.jar`

also check : [Security/ExecutableBit](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/ExecutableBit)

Comment: If necessary use `sudo` in front of the above command, like so: `sudo chmod +x /path/to/your/minecraft.jar`

Comment: the file is on my desktop named Minecraft.jar, so path should be /home/myusername/desktop/Minecraft.jar?

Comment: im running chrubuntu if this makes any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, a question I can answer!
Right click the .jar file and select properties. 
Go to permissions and click the box at the bottom 'Allow executing file as program'.
Close the window.
Open Ubuntu software centre.
Search for Java 7.
Install the package 'OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime'
Once installed, open the minecraft.jar file and it should work.
If not right click it, select 'open with...' and select Java 7 Runtime.
Thats it!

Tell me if it worked.

Comment: Im running chrubuntu so the option for "allow executing" box does not appear. Ive tried to do it via commands but seems impossible